# Table immediately preceded by a bolded line does not render

Tags: bug, markdown, tables

I have just written [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66901060/3840170) containing extensive quotes from the ECMA-262 specification. One of the elements quoted is a table.

**xyzzy**
|foo|bar|
|:-|:-|
|a|b|
|c|d|

The table displays correctly in the preview, but in the actual post, raw Markdown appears.

Can this be fixed? (By the way, is there a way to have a table `<caption>`?)

Comment: Yes, enter an extra white line after `xyxxy`

Comment: Looks fine by me when I visit your question

Comment: I fixed it in the answer now. It’s still a bug that the preview disagrees with the actual rendering.